# need help in optimizing mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i am writing a mysql query as below

```
SELECT `user_master`.`first_name`, 
       `city_name`, 
       `user_master`.`last_name`, 
       `user_master`.`user_master_id`, 
       `account_management_master`.`account_name`, 
       `donation_receipt_info`.`receipt_temple_id`, 
        date(dt) AS dt, 
       SUM(`donation_receipt_info`.`amount`) AS amount 
FROM (`donation_receipt_info`) 
JOIN `donation_receipt_master` ON donation_receipt_master`.`receipt_id`=`donation_receipt_info`.`receipt_id`
JOIN `account_management_master` ON `account_management_master`.`account_id`=`donation_receipt_info`.`account_id`
JOIN `user_master` ON `user_master`.`user_master_id`=`donation_receipt_master`.`user_master_id`
JOIN `user_address_info` ON `user_address_info`.`user_master_id`=`user_master`.`user_master_id`
JOIN `city_master` ON `city_master`.`city_id`=`user_address_info`.`city_id`
WHERE `donation_receipt_info`.`temple_id` = '1' 
GROUP BY `donation_receipt_info`.`receipt_id`, 
         `donation_receipt_info`.`account_id`
```

the table donation_receipt_info and master have approx 42k results the query is taking way to much time of about 5 to 6 minutes to execute in mysql itself.
can someone please help me optimize the query, any help or suggestion would be very helpful
Thanks.

Comment: Look at the output of EXPLAIN, look at what indexes are present/absent

Answer (score 1):

First, your query is impossible to read.  You should format it and learn to use table aliases:

```
SELECT um.first_name, city_name, um.last_name, um.user_master_id, amm.account_name, 
       dri.receipt_temple_id, date(dt) AS dt, SUM(dri.amount) AS amount
FROM donation_receipt_info dri JOIN
     donation_receipt_master drm
     ON drm.receipt_id = dri.receipt_id JOIN
     account_management_master amm
     ON amm.account_id = dri.account_id JOIN
     user_master um
     ON um.user_master_id = drm.user_master_id JOIN
     user_address_info uai
     ON uai.user_master_id = um.user_master_id JOIN
     city_master cm
     ON cm.city_id = uai.city_id
WHERE dri.temple_id = '1'
GROUP BY dri.receipt_id, dri.account_id;
```

Next.  Do all the tables have the obvious indexes?  That is, each table appears to have an id and these should be declared as keys (primary keys preferably).  For instance, `city_master(city_id)`.

Next, there should be an index on `donation_receipt_info(temple_id, receipt_id, account_id)`.  This should help with the `where`.  Note:  if `temple_id` is really an integer, the `where` clause should be expressed as `WHERE dri.temple_id = 1` -- no quotes.  You don't want MySQL to get confused and decide not to use the index.

These changes will probably help.  5-6 minutes seems like a long time for such a query.

Comment: Interesting how different people have different preferences. I, for one, thought OP's format is a lot easier, because the JOIN keyword is always on the left.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . The original question was not formatted; the formatting in the question was apparently done by pagogomez.

Comment: I did not even think to look. My mistake! Although, I suppose my comment still holds ha.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . Not to start a war or a discussion, but I do not like the `JOIN`s on the left.  I reserve the left for the SQL keywords that start clauses . . . such as `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY`.  `JOIN` is a keyword used within a clause, so I would never put it on the left.  Clearly, pagogomez disagrees.  But, that is not why I reformatted the code.